# Opera window.open without changing URL

Tags: javascript, opera

I am using javascript method window.open to get the reference to the other windows of mine service.

The main idea is that if I use window.open('', name ) and window with given name exsists then I get the reference to it (and if it is from same domain I can comunicate with it). If it does not the new window has url 'about:blank'. So if it is about:blank I am closing it.

That works on every browser except Opera... When I am calling window.open with empty string as first argument on every browser if the window with this name exsits I will get refenrence to it and nothing more. But not on Opera - there the URL of this window will be changed to about:blank.

Are there any way to workaround this on Opera?

Comment: Can you explain a little better as to what you want. May be some sample code or example will help clarify the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting `window.focus('name');` :)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there are still Presto Opera users out there, and here's a solution (more of a hack) for it (yes, browser sniffing is required):

`var popup = window.open("file:///D:/nonexistent_file", name);`

This way you'll get the window reference and a insignificant security exception in new window (if a new window with `about:blank` url was opened).